# Get Code from an Application running on BlueStacks using Python

Tags: python, automation, pywin32, bluestacks

I have an application installed in blue stacks and I want to get code from interface of application via automation but don't want to do it on front end. For that purpose , I am using pywin32 and getting blue stacks by using
hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, 'BlueStacks')
is there any way to get app and read code from its interface?